# Exporting OxyPlot chart to png in asp.net phoject

Tags: c#, asp.net, oxyplot

I'm using asp.net for generating pdf file. In pdf i must show plot. I decided using oxyplot with exporting it in png and inserting in pdf. The documentation says using PlotModel, filling it with series and axes and simply export by using PngExporting object. But when I'm trying generate it, nothing is presented except the axes.

The code I'm using:

```
var _plotModel = new OxyPlot.PlotModel()
            {
                PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyPlot.OxyColors.Transparent,
                LegendBorder = OxyPlot.OxyColors.Transparent,
                TitleToolTip = "Temperature",
                Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ru-Ru"),
                Series =
                {
                    new OxyPlot.Series.LineSeries()
                    {
                        ItemsSource = new List<SimplePointModel>
                        {
                            new SimplePointModel {  Date = DateTime.Now, Temperature = 36.6f },
                            new SimplePointModel {  Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), Temperature = 42.6f },
                            new SimplePointModel {  Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), Temperature = 48.6f },
                        },
                        MarkerFill = OxyPlot.OxyColor.Parse("#A9CF9C"),
                        MarkerType = OxyPlot.MarkerType.Circle,
                        MarkerSize = item.ListSegments[0].Count() == 1 ? 2 : 1,
                        DataFieldX = "Date",
                        DataFieldY = "Temperature",
                        XAxisKey = "Date",
                        YAxisKey = "Temperature",
                        Color = OxyPlot.OxyColor.Parse("#A9CF9C"),
                    }
                },
                Axes =
                {
                    new OxyPlot.Axes.DateTimeAxis()
                    {
                        Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Bottom,
                        Key = "Date",
                        ToolTip = "Temperature",
                        AbsoluteMinimum = OxyPlot.Axes.Axis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now.Date),
                        AbsoluteMaximum = OxyPlot.Axes.Axis.ToDouble(DateTime.Now.AddDays(10000))
                    },
                    new OxyPlot.Axes.LinearAxis()
                    {
                        Position = OxyPlot.Axes.AxisPosition.Left,
                        Key = "Temperature",
                        ToolTip = "Temperature",
                        IsZoomEnabled = false,
                        IsPanEnabled = false,
                    }
                }
            };
            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(Path.Combine(folder, "temp.png")))
            {
                PngExporter.Export(_plotModel, stream, 800, 400, OxyPlot.OxyColors.Transparent);
            }
```

What can I do?

Comment: DateTime.Now.AddDays(10000)? Try a value like 10 days. I think i might be a problem caused by scale of the X axis.

Comment: @kennyzx I tryed to do this, nothing is changed. It's just zoom property.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution: we must load data to **Points** list parameter in **Series** object instead of **ItemSource** parameter. **ItemSource** parameter used in mobile version of library.

Comment: Please add the code of the solution in the answer for completeness.